# Matching the two list of lists of different size and return the difference

Tags: python, list-comparison

I have two lists:

```
l1=[[12,3,C,-],[10,2,A,-]]
l2=[[8,3,X,W],[15,2,Y,W],[16,2,X,W],[17,3,V,W],[20,2,Z,W],[21,1,V,W].......]
```

Now i want to compare these two lists and fetch unmatched part from l2 into new list.I mean to say it should match l1[1] with the field l2[1] and return not matched list.
Matching means when the element in 2nd position of the sublist of l1 compared to the same position in the sublists of l2 it should be neglected and whatever doesn't match must be returned. Actually i have to iterate over both lists to get the comparison element. e.g. 3,2 in l1 and upon comparison it should return the sublist with second position element 1.
This is my approach:

```
l3=[x for x in l2 if x[1] not in l1[1]]
```

But it's returning me even the matched part also.What is wrong with it?

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by "matching". And also, why `l1` is a list of lists, when you are using only its first element (making the second element irrelevant).

Comment: Matching means when the element in 2nd position of the sublist of l1 compared to the same position in the sublists of l2 it should be neglected and whatever doesn't match must be returned. Actually i have to iterate over both lists to get the comparison element. e.g. 3,2 in l1 and upon comparison it should return the sublist with second position element 1.
is it clear enough now??

Comment: Consider improving your question to make this clear. Also, sample input with expected output would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Matching means when the element in 2nd position of the sublist of l1
>   compared to the same position in the sublists of l2 it should be
>   neglected and whatever doesn't match must be returned.

**Consider Adding the above statement in your comment to your question**

Reduce your first list to a list of key elements. In case, your list is considerable bigger, make it a set

Traverse your second list and filter it by comparing with the reduced list using membership operator

```
>>> l1=[[12,3,'C','-'],[10,2,'A','-']]
>>> l2=[[8,3,'X','W'],[15,2,'Y','W'],[16,2,'X','W'],[17,3,'V','W'],[20,2,'Z','W'],[21,1,'V','W']]
>>> key = set(e[1] for e in l1)
>>> [e for e in l2 if e[1] not in key]
[[21, 1, 'V', 'W']]
```

Comment: I think OP wants sublists where index `1` of the list does **not** match, so just `[21,1,'V','W']`

Comment: @C.B.: Agreed, just overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
l1=[[12,3,C,-],[10,2,A,-]]
l2=[[8,3,X,W],[15,2,Y,W],[16,2,X,W],[17,3,V,W],[20,2,Z,W],[21,1,V,W]]
```

You're approach was close but you want to use the `map` function to create a list of the second elements in `l1`

```
l3=[x for x in l2 if x[1] not in map( lambda y: y[1], l1) ]
```

Note `map` takes a function and a sequence and returns a list of the function results when applied to each member of the sequence (i.e. the second element of each sublist in `l1`).  If `l1` is very large you can make a set of the second elements which will remove duplicates and make membership checking O(1).

```
l1set = set( map( lambda y: y[1], l1) )
```

then the creation of `l3` would look like this,

```
l3=[x for x in l2 if x[1] not in l1set ]
```